# How to prove that $P(\pi_2 \mid \pi_1)=P\left(\mathbf{X} \in R_2 \mid \pi_1\right)=\int_{R_2=\Omega-R_1} f_1(\mathbf{x}) \,d \mathbf{x}$?

Tags: probability, classification, conditional

Let $f_1(\mathbf{x})$ and $f_2(\mathbf{x})$ be the probability density functions associated with the $p \times 1$ vector random variable $\mathbf{X}$ for the populations $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$, respectively. An object with associated measurements $\mathbf{x}$ must be assigned to either $\pi_1$ or $\pi_2$. Let $\Omega$ be the sample space of all $\mathbf{x}$ observations. Let $R_1$ be that set of $\mathbf{x}$ values for which we classify objects as $\pi_1$ and $R_2=\Omega-R_1$ be the remaining $\mathbf{x}$ values for which we classify objects as $\pi_2$. Since every object must be assigned to one and only one of the two populations, the sets $R_1$ and $R_2$ are mutually exclusive and exhaustive. **Why the following conditional probability is correct?**

$$
P(\pi_2 \mid \pi_1)=P\left(\mathbf{X} \in R_2 \mid \pi_1\right)=\int_{R_2=\Omega-R_1} f_1(\mathbf{x}) \,d \mathbf{x}
$$